# How can I access nested fields with JavacNode

Tags: java, abstract-syntax-tree, lombok

I'm new to lombok and AST. Here is a problem that I stuck for days. If it is not clear, please help me to clarify it, thank you.

I have a class look like this

```
class OrderFixture {
   @MyLombokAnnotation 
   private Order order = new Order(); 

}
```

My plan is to generate setter methods for the field order which looks like this:

```
class OrderFixture {
   private Order order = new Order(); 

   public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.order.setStatus(status);
   }
}
```

But I don't find a way to get fields of the order field with lombok API, here is my spike codes:

```
private JCTree.JCMethodDecl withStatusMethod(JavacNode fixtureClass, JavacNode targetField) {
    JavacTreeMaker treeMaker = fixtureClass.getTreeMaker();
    JCVariableDecl targetFieldDeclare = (JCVariableDecl) targetField.get();

    //get fields of target field
    // I can get targetField Type (Order in this case), But I don't know how to use it
}
```

I used `@PrintAST`, from the console, looks like the order field and its fields are not in the tree.

So is it possible to achieve my goal?